# Zipkin and Slueth

Tags: zipkin

As Zipkin client and Slueth dependencies are removed from spring boot how can I add log tracing in microservice project via docker ?

I tried adding zipkin dependency but it is not working for some reason my docker container is running which is running by docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin this command.

Answer (score 0):

Since Zipkin client and Sleuth dependencies have been removed from Spring Boot versions above 3.0, you'll need to use an alternative approach for tracing, which is still available for spring version 3.0 & above please refer to the below dependencies which you can add to your pom.xml.

pom.xml dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
      <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.yaml configurations:

```
# Micrometer configuration
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      - type: zipkin
        uri: http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
        step: 10s
        batch: true

# Zipkin configuration
zipkin:
  sender:
    type: web
    url: http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans

# Brave (Zipkin instrumentation) configuration
brave:
  tracing:
    serviceName: 'your service name'
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
```